# JAVA: I am trying to make a project that calculates the IQ loss on a given night depending on how many hours of sleep was lost

Tags: java, class, codio

My goal is to Write a utility class called Sleep, containing a static method called iqLoss. The iqLoss method should take a single parameter: an integer number representing the number of sleep hours missed on a given night. Then return an integer representing the IQ drop experienced as a result of that sleep deprivation. I dont know what the problem is since I am just beginner in Java. I am using an ide called "Codio" for my class so there are some things that I am unable to use with it, I am not aware of the limitations of the IDE. I have posted the main and class below, any tips would be very appreciated.

```
public class Sleep{
  public static int iqLoss(){
    int iq;
    int totaliqloss;
    if(iq >= 2){
      totaliqloss = totaliqloss + 2;
    }else if(iq<=2){
      totaliqloss = totaliqloss + 1;
    }
    return totaliqloss;
  }
}
```

```
public class SleepCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int iq;
    int normalsleep;
    
    System.out.println("What is your IQ (when fully rested)");
    iq = ConsoleIO.readInt();
    
    System.out.println("How many hours do you noramlly get");
    normalsleep = ConsoleIO.readInt();
    
    
    System.out.println("How many hours did you get last night?");
    int sleep;
    sleep = ConsoleIO.readInt;
    sleep = normalsleep - sleep;
    sleep = Sleep.iqLoss();

    System.out.println("How many hours did you get the night before last?");
    int sleep2;
    sleep2 = ConsoleIO.readInt;
    sleep2 = normalsleep - sleep2;
    sleep2 = Sleep.iqLoss();
    
    System.out.println("How many hours did you get the night before the night before last?");
    int sleep3;
    sleep3 = ConsoleIO.readInt;
    sleep3 = normalsleep - sleep3;
    sleep3 = Sleep.iqLoss();
    
    iq = iq - sleep - sleep2 - sleep3;
  }
}
```

```
SleepCalc.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    sleep = ConsoleIO.readInt;
                     ^
  symbol:   variable readInt
  location: class ConsoleIO
SleepCalc.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    sleep2 = ConsoleIO.readInt;
                      ^
  symbol:   variable readInt
  location: class ConsoleIO
SleepCalc.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    sleep3 = ConsoleIO.readInt;
                      ^
```

Comment: What leads you to believe something is wrong? Do you get a compiler error? Does the code do something you don't expect it to? You say there's a "problem" but you never tell us what it is

Comment: sorry, I will update the post with the compiler errors.

Comment: I don't think there is a class named `ConsoleIO` in the Java standard libraries. It doesn't sound very Java-ish and I don't find anything like it. Make sure you try to use the right class. Then you probably need to [`import`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) it.